# Setting ScrollViewer.ManipulationMode to System doesn't seem to work

Tags: windows-phone-8, windows-phone, scrollviewer

I have a hierarchical tree implemented using ListBox. I implemented item reordering method by holding an item and dragging it around.

To do this I intercept item's *Hold*, *ManipulationDelta* and *ManipulationCompleted* events. Because Listbox's ScrollViewer is in *ManipulationMode = ManipulationMode.System* by default, I need to set it to *ManipulationMode.Control* to disable it temporarily to be able to drag my item around.

If I won't do that, scrollviewer intercepts my *ManipulationDelta* events so when user tries to drag the item, he scrolls the scrollviewer instead and my item stays in fixed position.

Normally, after user drops the item i want to set it back to *ManipulationMode.System* (if I don't the tree structure scrolling remains laggy because item's template is somewhat heavy/complex).

```
private void ElementHold(object sender, GestureEventArgs e) {
    ....
    _scrollViewer.HorizontalScrollBarVisibility = ScrollBarVisibility.Disabled;
    _scrollViewer.VerticalScrollBarVisibility = ScrollBarVisibility.Disabled;   
    // works ok     
    _scrollViewer.SetValue(ScrollViewer.ManipulationModeProperty, ManipulationMode.Control);
}

private void ElementManipulationCompleted(object sender, ManipulationCompletedEventArgs e) {
    _scrollViewer.HorizontalScrollBarVisibility = ScrollBarVisibility.Auto;
    _scrollViewer.VerticalScrollBarVisibility = ScrollBarVisibility.Auto;

    // ▼ this doesn't seem to work. 
    // ▼ In the debugger ManipulationMode has correct value but scrolling 
    // ▼ still lags which means that scrollviewer stays in Control mode.
    _scrollViewer.SetValue(ScrollViewer.ManipulationModeProperty, ManipulationMode.System);
}
```

I've read that I can't switch ManipulationMode after ApplyTemplate() was called, but I also read that it *should* be possible if done by setting via dependency property instead of standard property.

What am I doing wrong here? Is it impossible to go back to System mode? If I go to other page and back to this one scrollViewer still lags. Only app restart works.

Answer (score 2):

Just set UseOptimizedManipulationRouting="False" to dragging item control to prevent Routing event to scrollviewer